# How do I tell what type of multitouch device an MTDeviceRef is

Tags: macos, cocoa, multi-touch

I'm trying to write a library to get the touch events from an Apple Magic Mouse.  I'm using the private framework MultitouchSupport.framework and use the code below to get a list of multitouch devices.  This works great, and my library works well, except for the fact that it gets touch events from all multitouch devices, such as the laptops trackpad, while I'd like to only get events from a Magic Mouse.  How can I tell what type of devices I am looking at to only monitor the mouse?

The code I use to listen for events is

```
        NSMutableArray* deviceList = (__bridge NSMutableArray*)MTDeviceCreateList(); //grab our device list

    for(int i = 0; i<[deviceList count]; i++) //iterate available devices
    {
        MTRegisterContactFrameCallback([deviceList objectAtIndex:i], touchCallback); //assign callback for device
        MTDeviceStart([deviceList objectAtIndex:i], 0); //start sending events
    }
```

so how can i filter out the MTDeviceRefs returned from MTDeviceCreateList to only start listening to magic mouse devices?  Or at the very least, filter out the default laptop trackpad?  Is there any documentation for using this MultitouchSupport.framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least four other ways to obtain a `MTDeviceRef`:

- `MTDeviceCreateDefault`
- `MTDeviceCreateFromDeviceID`
- `MTDeviceCreateFromGUID`
- `MTDeviceCreateFromService`

MultitouchSupport.framework being a private framework, you will have to reverse engineer it in order to understand what are the parameters you should pass to these functions.

Also, if you obtain a reference from one of these function, you should probably release the device ref with the `MTDeviceRelease` function.

Or you could try to filter out the trackpad with the `MTDeviceIsBuiltIn` function. Maybe *BuiltIn* means *laptop trackpad*. This is just a wild guess, I just looked at the symbols in the MultitouchSupport framework binary. Given the function name its signature is probably

`BOOL MTDeviceIsBuiltIn(MTDeviceRef device)`

Again, this is just a guess, I haven't actually tried.

Comment: So i ended up just filtering out the first item which happened to always be the trackpad, which was good enough for my limited usage, but these are good ideas and if I need to make it more robust I will look into them.  Thanks!

Comment: How did you look at the symbols?  I use nm but it doesn't give me much to go off of, is there a better way?

Comment: At the time I wrote the answer, I did not have the developer tools installed so I could not even use `nm`. I used `strings < /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/MultitouchSupport` But `nm -U` is really the best way to look at the symbols for a C API. I would use `class-dump` instead for an Objective-C API.

Comment: There's also `void MTDeviceGetTransportMethod(MTDeviceRef, int *);` which returns 1 for internal, 4 for bluetooth.

Comment: Also `MTDeviceGetFamilyID`. See possible values at https://github.com/JitouchProject/Jitouch/blob/3b5018e4bc839426a6ce0917cea6df753d19da10/Application/Gesture.m#L2930